# Drawing a scalloped rectangle

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to draw a scalloped rectangle with mouse like in below image

[image]

I am able to draw rectangle with code below

```js
function Rectangle(start, end) {
  var w = (end.x - start.x);
  var h = (end.y - start.y);
  return ["M", start.x, start.y, "L", (start.x + w), start.y, "L", start.x + w, start.y + h, "L", start.x, start.y + h, "L", start.x, start.y].join(' ');
}

var point;
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  point = {
    x: event.clientX,
    y: event.clientY
  }
});

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  var target = {
    x: event.clientX,
    y: event.clientY
  }
  if(point) {
    var str = Rectangle(point, target);
    document.getElementById('test').setAttribute('d', str);
  }
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
  point = null;
});
```

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
svg {
  height:100%;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<svg>
    <path id="test" style="stroke-width: 4; stroke: RGBA(212, 50, 105, 1.00); fill: none" />
  </svg>
```

But when I try to convert into scalloped rectangle I am seeing different patterns exactly matching [Infinite Monkey Theorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem)

The approach I tried is, draw a rectangular path on a virtual element. Take each point at length multiplied by 15 till total length. Then drawing arcs between those points. It is not working. Also, I want to avoid using `getPointAtLength` because it's mobile support is not great.

```js
var pathEle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
pathEle.setAttribute('d', rectangle(point, target));
window.pathEle = pathEle;

var points = [];
for (var i = 0; i < pathEle.getTotalLength(); i += 15) {
  points.push(pathEle.getPointAtLength(i));
}

document.getElementById('test1').setAttribute('d', toSVGPath(points));
```

Comment: And what happens if the length of the side of the rectangle is not a multiple of 15? How should that small leftover length be handled?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau It won't be symmetric. The first box in the attached image is a perfect example of what I want to achieve. Corners should become arcs. So the number 15 is randomly taken, I assume it should be calculated value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

I'm using arcs to make the scallops.  You may want to tweak how the scallops are calculated to get better corners. But I'll leave that to you.

```js
var scallopSize = 30;

function Rectangle(start, end) {
  var minX = Math.min(start.x, end.x);
  var minY = Math.min(start.y, end.y);
  var w = Math.abs(end.x - start.x);
  var h = Math.abs(end.y - start.y);

  // Calculate scallop sizes
  var numW = Math.round(w / scallopSize);
  if (numW === 0) numW = 1;
  var numH = Math.round(h / scallopSize);
  if (numH === 0) numH = 1;
  var stepW = w / numW;
  var stepH = h / numH;

  // top
  var p = minX + stepW/2;  // start each size at half a scallop along
  var path = ["M", p, minY];
  for (var i=1; i < numW; i++) {   // numW-1 scallops per side
    p += stepW;
    path.push('A');
    path.push(stepW/2 + 1);   // Add 1 to the radius to ensure it's
    path.push(stepW/2 + 1);   // big enough to span the stepW
    path.push("0 0 1");
    path.push(p);
    path.push(minY);
  }
  // top right
  var p = minY + stepH/2;
  path.push('A');
  path.push(stepH/2.8);  // 2 * sqrt(2)
  path.push(stepH/2.8);  // corners are a little smaller than the scallops
  path.push("0 0 1");
  path.push(minX + w);
  path.push(p);
  // right
  for (var i=1; i < numH; i++) {
    p += stepH;
    path.push('A');
    path.push(stepH/2 + 1);
    path.push(stepH/2 + 1);
    path.push("0 0 1");
    path.push(minX + w);
    path.push(p);
  }
  // bottom right
  var p = minX + w - stepW/2;
  path.push('A');
  path.push(stepH/2.8);
  path.push(stepH/2.8);  
  path.push("0 0 1");
  path.push(p);
  path.push(minY + h);
  // bottom
  for (var i=1; i < numW; i++) {
    p -= stepW;
    path.push('A');
    path.push(stepW/2 + 1);
    path.push(stepW/2 + 1);
    path.push("0 0 1");
    path.push(p);
    path.push(minY + h);
  }
  // bottom left
  var p = minY + h - stepH/2;
  path.push('A');
  path.push(stepH/2.8);
  path.push(stepH/2.8);  
  path.push("0 0 1");
  path.push(minX);
  path.push(p);
  // left
  for (var i=1; i < numH; i++) {
    p -= stepH;
    path.push('A');
    path.push(stepH/2 + 1);
    path.push(stepH/2 + 1);
    path.push("0 0 1");
    path.push(minX);
    path.push(p);
  }
  // top left
  path.push('A');
  path.push(stepH/2.8);
  path.push(stepH/2.8);  
  path.push("0 0 1");
  path.push(minX + stepW/2);
  path.push(minY);
  path.push('Z');

  return path.join(' ');
}

var point;
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  point = {
    x: event.clientX,
    y: event.clientY
  }
});

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  var target = {
    x: event.clientX,
    y: event.clientY
  }
  if(point) {
    var str = Rectangle(point, target);
    document.getElementById('test').setAttribute('d', str);
  }
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
  point = null;
});
```

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
svg {
  height:100%;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<svg>
    <path id="test" style="stroke-width: 4; stroke: RGBA(212, 50, 105, 1.00); fill: none" />
  </svg>
```

Comment: This is the exact thing I am looking for. Can you please tweak corners also to be the same size as other scallops.

Comment: I'll leave that as an exercise for you.  My answer was intended to show you how to get started. If you would like to hire me to get this example working exactly as you want, then let me know.

Comment: It's working now. :) BTW If you want to work with me together I am more than glad to hear that :) Drop an email if ready please